# XML Not Loading in FF or IE, Works In Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, load, xmlhttprequest, soundcloud

Please take a look at the following link:
http://www.nba.com/warriors/audiotrack_test_000005.html?mark-jackson-on-the-dan

This works properly (meaning it appends the audio track onto the page) in Chrome but fails at different points in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

In IE it fails at the line:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/goldenstatewarriors/tracks?client_id=02db8e29aa2fb5bf590f478b73137c67");
```

In FF it fails at the line below that:

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("track");
```

I've never had a cross-browser XML loading problem like this before, but this is the first time I am loading XML from a server other than my own.

Any solutions available? SoundCloud also offers JSON but I have not worked with that much...

Comment: I recommend learning about JSON, it's really important and typically smaller in size than XML.

Comment: Looking into JSON, have a question about importing JSON objects which I'll do some research/possibly start another thread if I come up empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at it in Firefox and firebug shows that the response from api.soundcloud is returned as

```
content-type: text/html.
```

The XMLHttpRequest in your loadXMLDoc gets the reponse in the responseText property and not the responseXML.

Looking on the soundcloud website (never used it myself) you can specify the required format by changing your call to

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/goldenstatewarriors/tracks?client_id=02db8e29aa2fb5bf590f478b73137c67&format=xml");
```

adding the

```
&format=xml
```

to the call made it work for me in firefox at least.

Comment: Thanks this did fix it in Firefox although still not working in IE. I'll keep digging/look into JSON